# Laravel eloquent relationship issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

this is my website model

```
  class Website extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'website';

   public function links()
   {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Website_links')->where('crawler_status',1);
   }

}
```

and controller code

```
 if(Request::ajax()){

        $validator = Validator::make(Request::all(), [
            'page' => 'required',
        ]);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return Response::json(['success'=>false,'error'=>$validator->errors()->toArray()]);
        }

        $page = Request::get('page');
        $websites_data = Website::where('user_id',Auth::id())->skip(3*($page-1))->take(3)->get();
        return Response::json(['success'=>true,'success_data'=>$websites_data]);
    }
```

and javascrpit code

```
$(result.success_data).each(function( index,el) {
                console.log(el.project_name,el.website_url,el.links);
            });
```

here i am getting undefined on el.links.
in my html i am getting it perfect like this

```
@foreach($data as $website)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$website['project_name']}}
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="{{$website['website_url']}}">{{$website['website_url']}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{count($website->links)}}</td></tr>
@endforeach
```

i want to count el.links in javascript like i have done in html.in javascript first two values project_name and website_url is coming perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to load the relationship to get it included in the JSON output.

Eager load it....

```
$websites_data = Website::with('links')->where('user_id',Auth::id())->skip(3*($page-1))->take(3)->get();
```

or lazy load it

```
$websites_data = Website::where('user_id',Auth::id())->skip(3*($page-1))->take(3)->get();
$websites_data->load('links');
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var obj = JSON.parse(el);
console.log(obj.project_name,obj.website,el.links)
```